# Android databinding cannot find the setter for attribute

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to use android databinding library with Kotlin and want provide custom attribute for `RecyclerView`. For this I've created a file with this code:

```
@BindingAdapter("config")
fun configRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, config: RecyclerViewConfig) {
    config.apply(recyclerView)
}
```

Where `RecyclerViewConfig` is:

```
class RecyclerViewConfig private constructor(
    val adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>,
    val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
    val isNestedScrollingEnabled: Boolean,
    val hasFixedSize: Boolean
) {

    fun apply(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = isNestedScrollingEnabled
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(hasFixedSize)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    class Builder {

        private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
        private var isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
        private var hasFixedSize = true

        fun adapter(adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>): Builder {
            this.adapter = adapter
            return this
        }

        fun layoutManager(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager): Builder {
            this.layoutManager = layoutManager
            return this
        }

        fun nestedScrollingEnabled(isNestedScrollingEnabled: Boolean): Builder {
            this.isNestedScrollingEnabled = isNestedScrollingEnabled
            return this
        }

        fun hasFixedSize(hasFixedSize: Boolean): Builder {
            this.hasFixedSize = hasFixedSize
            return this
        }

        fun build() = RecyclerViewConfig(adapter, layoutManager, isNestedScrollingEnabled, hasFixedSize)
    }

}
```

Also I have my own`ViewModel` with `RecyclerViewConfig` inside:

```
class AdvertPageViewModel(val context: Context) : RecyclerViewModel {

    private val adapter: RealtyAdvertAdapter
    private val listener: OnPageContentsClickListener
    private val config: RecyclerViewConfig

    init {
        listener = createListener()
        config = createConfig()
        adapter = RealtyAdvertAdapter(createAdvert().toPageItems(), listener)
    }

    override fun getConfig() = config

    private fun createConfig() =
            RecyclerViewConfig.Builder()
                    .adapter(adapter)
                    .layoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(context))
                    .build()


    private fun createListener() = object: OnPageContentsClickListener {

        override fun onCallButtonClick(phone: String) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCallButtonClick")
        }

        override fun onWriteButtonClick(phone: String) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onWriteButtonClick")
        }

    }
}
```

I create it like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = AdvertPageViewModel(context)
    if (view != null) {
        val binding = FragmentAdvertPageBinding.bind(view)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

And there's layout for Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
      type="ru.am.realty.ui.fragments.advertpage.AdvertPageViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:config="@{viewModel.getConfig()}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The problem is that when I try to build application, there's an error occured:

```
Error:(20, 27) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:config' with 
parameter type ru.am.realty.ui.base.viewmodel.RecyclerViewConfig on 
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.
```

So, I was looking for any solutions, but without success. And I have no idea, what's wrong with my code

UPDATE: there's gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

    // Rx
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'

    //di
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'

    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: could you post your `build.gradle` as well ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Added gradle to my question

Comment: Assuming your `BindingAdapter` is at the file level, this should work. Perhaps you need to clean and rebuild? You can always decompile the kotlin to java to ensure it is doing the right thing (which it should be).

Comment: Same problem here. I have exactly same code. The only difference is that my custom atribute is boolean. Any solution?